# How to position images and equations well?

Tags: floats, equations, formatting, align, numbering

I would like to have the figures behind the equations (the first figure behind the first equation and the second figure behind the second equation), but I want the **equation label to be aligned to the right** (like it is right now) and the figures to count as **figures in the caption**.

I tried using *minipages*, but it looked poorly formatted and the figures didn't show up in the Figure list...

Any help? Thanks in advance. I have the code below the picture.

[image: what I have]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}\include{Acronyms}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\bf\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black
}

\author{\textbf{Names}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \int\limits_{V} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}V = \oint\limits_{S} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S \label{eq:gauss_theorem} \\
    \int\limits_{S} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S = \oint\limits_{C} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}r \label{eq:stokes_theorem}
\end{align}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [surface] 
\draw   (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$C$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};


\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of a \\ two-dimensional surface S with \\ a contour C.} \label{fig:surface_contour}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [volume] 
\draw   (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [horizontal depth line] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (183.26,143.67) .. controls (223.26,113.67) and (321.28,118.53) .. (346.6,142.43) ;
%Curve Lines [vertical depth line] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (259.27,158.43) .. controls (287.93,139.77) and (269.27,88.43) .. (244.6,89.1) ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$V$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};


\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of a \\ three-dimensional volume V with \\ a surface S.} \label{fig:volume_surface}
    \end{minipage}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You might try  the  `floatrow` package. Unrelated: in an align environment, if you don't specify the alignment points with an ampersand, the equations are right-aligned.

Comment: The problem is that when I create a minipage environment, the equation label doesn't align to the right like the picture I attached here, it is immediately after the equation

Comment: Please don't quickly accept the very first answer that gets posted, even if it's a good one, unless you want to *actively discourage* others from contributing further answers. Please see the guidelines for new users for why people are encouraged to wait a few hours at least, and maybe even a day or more, before applying a checkmark to a particular answer.

Comment: I removed the checkmark, I was not aware of that. Thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont' think that an arrangement like this really helps the reader to reference the relevant figure or equation if cited somewhere else in the text. Still, it can be achieved with the following approach:

You can put the two pictures inside boxes and then place them after the equations. Note that the pictures are then no more `figures`, that is, they are no more in a floating environment. Hence, you cannot use `\caption` anymore. You can, however, load the package `caption` that provides the `\captionof` macro which can be used for captions outside of floats. (I removed all the packages that are unnecessary for this example.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\figa}
\savebox{\figa}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [surface] 
\draw   (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$C$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};

\end{tikzpicture}\par
\captionof{figure}{Example of a \\ two-dimensional surface S with \\ a contour C.} \label{fig:surface_contour}
\end{minipage}%
}

\newsavebox{\figb}
\savebox{\figb}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [volume] 
\draw   (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [horizontal depth line] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (183.26,143.67) .. controls (223.26,113.67) and (321.28,118.53) .. (346.6,142.43) ;
%Curve Lines [vertical depth line] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (259.27,158.43) .. controls (287.93,139.77) and (269.27,88.43) .. (244.6,89.1) ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$V$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};

\end{tikzpicture}\par
\captionof{figure}{Example of a \\ three-dimensional volume V with \\ a surface S.} \label{fig:volume_surface}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{align}
    &\int\limits_{V} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}V = \oint\limits_{S} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S \label{eq:gauss_theorem}  && \raisebox{-6em}{\usebox{\figa}} \\
    &\int\limits_{S} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S = \oint\limits_{C} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}r \label{eq:stokes_theorem} && \raisebox{-6em}{\usebox{\figb}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, it may be better to place the pictures before the equations:

```
\begin{align}
    &\raisebox{-6em}{\usebox{\figa}} && \int\limits_{V} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}V = \oint\limits_{S} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S \label{eq:gauss_theorem} \\
    &\raisebox{-6em}{\usebox{\figb}} && \int\limits_{S} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S = \oint\limits_{C} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}r \label{eq:stokes_theorem}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jasper, but I don't think the equation number separated from the equation by the image looks good... but thanks anyway

Comment: Well, I thought, that this was what you are after, in the end, since you said, that the equation label should be aligned to the right.

Comment: I do, but, in your solution, I would like to switch the figures with the equations, and it would be perfect

Comment: Then just rearrange it in the `align` environment: `&\raisebox{-6em}{\usebox{\figa}} && \int\limits_{V} div \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}V = \oint\limits_{S} n \ \mathbf{a} \ \mathrm{d}S \label{eq:gauss_theorem}` it would be then for the first line.

Comment: but would the label remain at the right?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the equations look fine, except that there seems to be no good reason for using `\int\limits` instead of just `\int`. However, that may be a purely stylisic "thing", in which case do keep using `\int\limits`.

The problem is, rather, that each `minipage` is only `0.4\textwidth` wide and that they're set to the left instead of centered. Centering the minipages and centering their contents would seem to be a good idea.

The framelines in the following screenshot are there just to give a good sense of the width of the textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%% (I've simplified the preamble as much as possible for this example.)
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- unless you have an excellent reason for using 'OT1'
%\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bib.bib}

%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{placeins}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' env.
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,showframe]{geometry} % remove 'showframe' in real doc.
%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}\include{Acronyms}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\bf\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{
%    colorlinks,
%    citecolor=black,
%    filecolor=black,
%    linkcolor=blue,
%    urlcolor=black
%}

%\author{\textbf{Names}
%\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \int_{V} div \ \mathbf{a} \,\mathrm{d}V = \oint_{S} n \ \mathbf{a} \,\mathrm{d}S \label{eq:gauss_theorem} \\[1ex]
    \int_{S} div \ \mathbf{a} \,\mathrm{d}S = \oint_{C} n \ \mathbf{a} \,\mathrm{d}r \label{eq:stokes_theorem}
\end{align}
    
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\hfill % first of three '\hfill' directives
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering % <-- center the contents of the 'minipage' env.
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [surface] 
\draw   (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$C$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example of a two-dimensional surface $S$ with a contour $C$.} \label{fig:surface_contour}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [volume] 
\draw   (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [horizontal depth line] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (183.26,143.67) .. controls (223.26,113.67) and (321.28,118.53) .. (346.6,142.43) ;
%Curve Lines [vertical depth line] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (259.27,158.43) .. controls (287.93,139.77) and (269.27,88.43) .. (244.6,89.1) ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [arrow] 
\draw    (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$V$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example of a three-dimensional volume $V$ with a surface $S$.} \label{fig:volume_surface}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\null
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mico. Also thank you for clarifying the code, as it helped me learn more about how latex works. The picture looks better with your input, and I may keep the original layout with your input.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution :-)

- for positioning of equations and belonging images is used `tabularx`
- image is redrawn (simplified and shorter code)
- for math is used `nccmath` package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections,
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}%{figure}[ht]
    \tikzset{x=0.8pt, y=0.8pt,
        }
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X C }
\begin{fleqn}%[1em]
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:gauss_theorem}
\int_{V} \nabla\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}V = \oint_{S} n\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}S
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, thick, xscale=1, yscale=-1]
\draw[name path=P]   
        (0,0)   .. controls (20,-10) and ( 37,-20) .. ( 90, 0) node[above  left=3mm] {$C$}
                .. controls (142,20) and (166, 66) .. ( 90,60) 
                .. controls ( 13,53) and (- 5, 82) .. (-25,52) node[above right=2mm and 7mm] {$S$}
                .. controls (-55,22) and (-20, 10) .. (  0, 0);
% lines
\coordinate (c1) at (10,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-135:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 135:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
\coordinate (c1) at (90,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-45:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 45:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Example of a two-dimensional surface S with a contour $C$.} \label{fig:surface_contour}
    \\
\begin{fleqn}%[1em]    
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:gauss_theorem}
\int_{V} \nabla\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}S = \oint_{S} n\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}r
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, thick, xscale=1, yscale=-1]
\draw[name path=P]
        (0,0)   .. controls (20,-10) and ( 37,-20) .. ( 90, 0) node[above  left=3mm] {$S$}
                .. controls (142,20) and (166, 66) .. ( 90,60)
                .. controls ( 13,53) and (- 5, 82) .. (-25,52) node[above right=2mm and 7mm] {$V$}
                .. controls (-55,22) and (-20, 10) .. (  0, 0);
% lines
\coordinate (c1) at (10,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-135:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 135:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
\coordinate (c1) at (90,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-45:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 45:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
% segments
\draw[dotted]
        (-32,42) .. controls (22,12) and (111, 17) .. (138, 41)
        ( 54,58) .. controls (77,38) and ( 59,-13) .. ( 41,-11) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Example of a three-dimensional volume $V$ with a surface $S$.} \label{fig:volume_surface}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}%{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
As you say in comment below,. you like to have interchanged images and  equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections,
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}%{figure}[ht]
    \tikzset{x=0.8pt, y=0.8pt,
        }
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ C X }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, thick, xscale=1, yscale=-1]
\draw[name path=P]
        (0,0)   .. controls (20,-10) and ( 37,-20) .. ( 90, 0) node[above  left=3mm] {$C$}
                .. controls (142,20) and (166, 66) .. ( 90,60)
                .. controls ( 13,53) and (- 5, 82) .. (-25,52) node[above right=2mm and 7mm] {$S$}
                .. controls (-55,22) and (-20, 10) .. (  0, 0);
% lines
\coordinate (c1) at (10,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-135:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 135:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
\coordinate (c1) at (90,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-45:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 45:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Example of a two-dimensional surface S with a contour $C$.} \label{fig:surface_contour}
    &   \begin{fleqn}%[1em]
        \begin{equation}\label{eq:gauss_theorem}
    \int_{V} \nabla\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}V = \oint_{S} n\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}S
        \end{equation}
        \end{fleqn}         \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, thick, xscale=1, yscale=-1]
\draw[name path=P]
        (0,0)   .. controls (20,-10) and ( 37,-20) .. ( 90, 0) node[above  left=3mm] {$S$}
                .. controls (142,20) and (166, 66) .. ( 90,60)
                .. controls ( 13,53) and (- 5, 82) .. (-25,52) node[above right=2mm and 7mm] {$V$}
                .. controls (-55,22) and (-20, 10) .. (  0, 0);
% lines
\coordinate (c1) at (10,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-135:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 135:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
\coordinate (c1) at (90,30);
\path[name path=a1]  (c1) -- ++ (-45:80) coordinate[label=$a$] (c11) {};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a1, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c11);
\path[name path=a2]  (c1) -- ++ ( 45:80) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (c12){};
\draw[name intersections={of=P and a2, by=b},->]        (b) -- (c12);
% segments
\draw[dotted]
        (-32,42) .. controls (22,12) and (111, 17) .. (138, 41)
        ( 54,58) .. controls (77,38) and ( 59,-13) .. ( 41,-11) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Example of a three-dimensional volume $V$ with a surface $S$.} \label{fig:volume_surface}
    &   \begin{fleqn}%[1em]
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:gauss_theorem}
\int_{V} \nabla\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}S = \oint_{S} n\mathbf{a}\,\mathrm{d}r
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}%{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that with the equations on the left, the reader can easily not see the numbering very well. Ideally, the pictures and equations would be switched.

Comment: @aaa This is no big problem. just switch column types and column contents. See addendum to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Zarko... Looking at your solutions, I'm curious why you changed the vector names from n to a... why did you make this switch?

Comment: @aaa, names of vector can be easy to change. Just write `n` instead of `a`: `coordinate[label=$n$]`. I don't remember now, why I changed their names.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\divg}{div}
 \newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}\include{Acronyms}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\bf\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black}

\author{\textbf{Names}}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\vskip 1cm

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
    \int\limits_{S} \divg \mathbf{a} \dd S = \oint\limits_{C} n \ \mathbf{a} \dd r \label{eq:stokes_theorem}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
    \int\limits_{V} \divg \mathbf{a} \dd V = \oint\limits_{S} n \ \mathbf{a} \dd S \label{eq:gauss_theorem}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
\renewcommand*{\floatrowsep}{\hskip 4em}
    \begin{floatrow}[2] \centering
\ffigbox[1.15\FBwidth]{%
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Polygon Curved [surface]
\draw (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$C$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\caption{Example of a two-dimensional surface S with a contour C.} \label{fig:surface_contour}}
%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt
\hskip 3em\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-0.9,xscale=0.9]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300
%Shape: Polygon Curved [volume]
\draw (210.18,101) .. controls (230.18,91) and (247.72,81.05) .. (300.18,101) .. controls (352.65,120.95) and (376.6,167.77) .. (300.18,161) .. controls (223.77,154.23) and (205.93,183.77) .. (185.93,153.77) .. controls (165.93,123.77) and (190.18,111) .. (210.18,101) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [horizontal depth line]
\draw [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}] (183.26,143.67) .. controls (223.26,113.67) and (321.28,118.53) .. (346.6,142.43) ;
%Curve Lines [vertical depth line]
\draw [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}] (259.27,158.43) .. controls (287.93,139.77) and (269.27,88.43) .. (244.6,89.1) ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (186.59,115) -- (162.75,91.86) ;
\draw [shift={(160.6,89.77)}, rotate = 404.15] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (194.6,163.1) -- (166.92,185.86) ;
\draw [shift={(164.6,187.77)}, rotate = 320.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (289.92,160.33) -- (288.71,192.1) ;
\draw [shift={(288.6,195.1)}, rotate = 272.18] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [arrow]
\draw (326.59,114.33) -- (352.99,91.72) ;
\draw [shift={(355.27,89.77)}, rotate = 499.42] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 } ][line width=0.08] [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle ;
% Text Node
\draw (236.59,135) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$V$};
% Text Node
\draw (269.92,67) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (167,77) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (158,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (298,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
% Text Node
\draw (359,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt] [xscale=0.7,yscale=0.7] [align=left] {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\caption{Example of a three-dimensional volume V with \ a surface S.} \label{fig:volume_surface}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like the equations to be on the right side of the figures, since the numbering of the equations should be on the right of the margin.

Comment: There is not enough space on the page width  to have figures and equations on the same row. Another solution would be to have a figure and the corresponding equation aligned, which implies a row per figure/equation.